# Crazy queen in checkers

Tags: strategy, optimization, checkerboard

**Checkers**
Checkers, also called draughts, is an interesting game. all pieces are placed on black tile and are all pawns at the start. When a pawn reach the final line, a powerful piece is created: the Queen. It can move multiple tiles on the same move.

**Question**
On a `10*10`checkers field, with international checkers rule. If you can place one white queen anywhere on the checker,
**What is the maximum number of black pawn you can take in a row?**
**Can you prove that this number is optimal?**

**Some reminders**
I want to remind that queen can go back, stop anywhere behind the pawn taken. Pawn won't disapear until the end of the whole move (so their tile will remain inaccessible for the queen) and you can't eat the same pawn twice!

Good luck!
Source: [diophante.fr](http://www.diophante.fr/problemes-par-themes/jeux-de-plateaux/1218-j122-la-grande-rafle-de-la-dame)

Comment: Do you have a tool to manually place pawns?

Comment: I'm strugling to find this sorry! If anyone encounter one, post it here, I will incorporate it in my question!

Comment: Is it necessary for the position to be reachable by a theoretically legal game of checkers?

Comment: Well no. No need for the position to be reachable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a possible solution with

> 19 captured pieces

..so the [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64945/36023) that proved that the maximum is three less probably needs some work. :-)

> [image]

I tried to fit more black pieces in while making sure that each piece is "jumpable", that is, it has two empty spaces on opposite sides of it. The likely arrangement of filling alternating diagonals surprisingly doesn't fit all that many pieces, and out of all the arrangements I tried, only one has more pieces than the solution above:

> [image]

That one doesn't have a path to capture all the pieces though: the marked squares near the corners have exactly one way to enter or exit them, and there's no way to capture the neighbouring pieces without visiting those squares. Therefore, each marked square would need to be an endpoint for the path, and given that there are four such squares, this is clearly impossible.

Although this does not constitute a formal proof on any kind, I myself am convinced that the above answer is the best one I'm ever going to find.

Comment: Apparently, [this position](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18950) is reachable.

Comment: @noedne, No way, out of all the possible symmetries and starting positions for the white king (there are many), that answer has chosen the exact same ones as I did!

Comment: It is a fairly natural spot. Unfortunate that that answer lacks any justification for the minimum.

Comment: the question you just link seems to agree Bass for the maximum number of pawn taken. In fact my question seems to be a duplicate of this question...

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably not right, as I've just been doodling during a meeting, but the longest contiguous path I could make captured

> 16

I'm not sure how to prove it mathematically, but the path runs:

> 0) A3
> 1) C5
> 2) A7
> 3) C9
> 4) E7
> 5) C5
> 6) E3
> 7) G1
> 8) I3
> 9) G5
> 10) I7
> 11) G9
> 12) E7
> 13) G5
> 14) E3
> 15) C1
> 16) A3

Answer (score 1):

I can prove that UselessInfoMine's solution is optimal. Divide the black squares of the checkerboard into two groups, A and B, as shown. Every capturing hop is between two squares of the same group, hopping over a square of the opposite group. This means that all the captured pieces must be on squares of the same group. Furthermore, captured pieces cannot be on the edge. Since  there are only sixteen internal squares in each group, a queen can only capture sixteen pieces in a single turn, which is achieved by UselessInfoMine's solution.

```
A   A   A   A   A
  B   B   B   B   B
A   A   A   A   A
  B   B   B   B   B
A   A   A   A   A
  B   B   B   B   B
A   A   A   A   A
  B   B   B   B   B
A   A   A   A   A
  B   B   B   B   B
```

Comment: You are using American Checkers rules, not International Checkers.

Comment: @Acccumulation I see! I learned something new today.

Comment: Seiriously? There are rules that allow you to move extra empty squares after captures? I have never heard that before.

Answer (score 1):

If we do not require all the captured pawns to remain until the end of the jump sequence, then there is even a solution with 22 captures:

[image: Queen at A2, captures C4,E6,G8,I8,I6,I4,I2,G2,G4,G6,D9,B9,B7,B5,C2,E2,E4,D7,H7,H3,D3,C8]

But I don't even think this is the maximum. Anyway, since this is not an answer to the question as stated, let me know if you think it should be deleted.

Comment: Your #19 is not valid due to the presence of the #3 and #5 pawns, which remain in position until the move is complete.

Comment: @DanielMathias: Is that the rule for checkers?

Comment: It is explicitly stated in the question under the heading 'Some reminders'

Comment: @DanielMathias: Thanks, I missed that additional constraint; I edited my post.